# Как циклом добавить запись в документ microsoft word?

Tags: python, ms-word

Имеется шаблон документа word `шаблон.docs`:

```
{{id}} some text {{id}} other words {{id}}
```

код программы:

```
list_data=[
 {'id':'1', 'name':'вася', 'password':'123'},
 {'id':'2', 'name':'john', 'password':'321'},
 {'id':'3', 'name':'mike', 'password':'555'}
 ]

for i in list_data:
    doc = DocxTemplate("шаблон.docx")
    context = {'id': i['id']}
  
    doc.render(context)

doc.save(f"{output.docx")
```

в файле output.docx получаю:

```
1 some text 1 other words 1
```

как получить результат в файл `output.docx`:

```
1 some text 2 other words 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать разные переменные в шаблоне.

```
{{id1}} some text {{id2}} other words {{id3}}
```

И в цикле уже построить массив контекста с другими ключами, а рендер вызвать после цикла.

```
context = {};
doc = DocxTemplate("шаблон.docx")

for i in list_data:
    context['id'+i['id']]=i['id']}
      
doc.render(context)
```

Comment: из name и password это по такому же принципу будет работать?

Comment: Да, идея та же.

Comment: context{['id'+i['id']]=i['id']} - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Если вы хотите подставить в [ ] число id, то используйте f ссылки
`{[f'{id}'+i[f'{id}']]=i[f'{id}']}`

Comment: context['id'+i['id']] = {i['id']}, потерялась открывающая скобка

Comment: @Сергей, компилируется без ошибок, но и в output.docx пусто в местах, где должны быть id

Comment: У меня вот такое выдает {'1'} some text {'2'} other words {'3'}

Comment: @Сергей, из name и password по аналогии работать не будет